# Foundation 4 MVC4 Grid Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, zurb-foundation

Some context: 
  Foundation 4.0.9 SaSS & Compass(Newbie), ASP.net MVC 4
  Device: Screen
  Chrome/26.0.1410.64
  Can Also reproduce issue in User Agents:  Firefox, Chrome, IE
  Windows 7 64-bit

I have an issue where a single column appears centred/offset from the left edge of a containing row. What I expect is the column to be flush against the row's left edge?

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div style="width: 500px; height: 500px;  outline: solid black 1px"> </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meanFiddler/aWNBp/

I am aware that Foundation includes classes to center columns such as large-centred although my example does not apply any directly and I could not see them being applied by external stylesheets under the chrome dev tools panel.

Is anybody aware of any in-depth tutorials of using Foundation 4?

Cheers

Comment: The column is already on the left edge as shown in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks replying. This is what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GTyKm.png  The column (in blue) appears in the middle of the row (orange) Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I'm not seeing the column you've made orange (winxp, latest chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the panel div and you should see your desired result. Panel adds margin and/or padding which, I assume, is what you *don't* want.

EDIT: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but, it also might be unnecessary to set the width to 500px, as a 12-column grid will span the entire width by default (960px).

Comment: Thanks CL75, I've updated my fiddle by removing the panel width constraint. However, if I stretch the viewport wide enough I end up with spacing either side of the 12 column, large enough for the col to appear centered. Here is what I see http://imgur.com/V3NWoXX   I'm not sure how to control this. I would like to have a single column spanning the entire with of the client surface.

Comment: If all you want is a full-width column, then remove the 500px width declaration like I said, from the inner-most div. See http://jsfiddle.net/aWNBp/4/. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Almost. When you stretch the jsfiddle viewport horizontally wide enough, we end up with significant spacing either side of the full width 12 column -  as seen here imgur.com/V3NWoXX

Comment: Hmmm.... I must not be understanding your desired result. Can you paste a picture of how you want things to look? Then I can achieve that via Foundation.